# How to get current Principal in Spring Boot app that uses Redis session store

Tags: spring, spring-boot, redis, saml-2.0, spring-session

I have a number of Spring Boot (release 1.5.3) microservice applications all sharing a Redis session store. I have the following dependencies on the classpath and users are able to login and their sessions are stored in Redis:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-session</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

The controller endpoints in each microservice use the @Preauthorize annotation to ensure the current user has appropriate granted authority to invoke the endpoint. The security seems to be set up correctly as these annotations do indeed ensure only those users with the correct roles can invoke. However, I also require to output the name of the user that is trying to invoke the endpoint to an audit log. To do this I have the following method that should return the user name as a string:

```
private String userDetailsString() {
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
    SecurityContext context = getSecurityContext();
    Authentication authentication = context.getAuthentication();
    if(authentication != null) {
        UserDetails principal = (UserDetails)authentication.getPrincipal();
        buf.append("Requested by: ");
        buf.append(principal.getUsername());
    } else {
        buf.append("Requested by: null");
    }
    return buf.toString();
}

protected SecurityContext getSecurityContext() {
    return SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
}
```

However, the Authentication object is always null. Why is this? And what is the preferred means of accessing the current Principal in such an application? Note this code needs to reside outside of a Controller class.

I'm guessing the code behind the @Preauthorize annotation must somehow be accessing this Principal in order to determine if they have the appropriate roles?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `EventListener` for success: `AuthorizedEvent` or failure `AuthorizationFailureEvent`

```
@EventListener(value = {AuthorizedEvent.class})
public void onApplicationEvent(AuthorizedEvent event) {
   log.info("Authorization : {}", event.getAuthentication().getName());
}
```

Comment: Thanks to your suggestion I subsequently found this tutorial which expands on your idea https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-authentication-audit